# R loop for several dataframes using Lavaan

Tags: r, loops, r-lavaan

I'm currently working on data with 8 waves, each wave is for now stored in it's own dataframe. I've done most of the data cleaning with a lot of repetition, since I couldn't figure out how to make R run the same script over different dataframes. Now I want to do a CFA using Lavaan, and I notice the script is getting very messy, with CFA's being done for multiple variables over all 8 waves. I would love to find a way to simplify my script, so that it's clear for both me and others. Underneath you can find a short example of what the 'long' version of the code would look like, but I'm hoping to get some help in shortening it!

I've tried using a for-loop, but I could not get it to work.

If you have any tips, please let me know so I can stop copy-pasting the same code and replacing the number in the df!

```
# Example with 2 waves in 2 df
model_ADI_aff <- "aff =~ bds89 + bds39 + bds50 + bds29 + bds84 + bds49 + bds70 + bds88 + bds11 + bds28
                "
fit_ADI_aff_1 <- cfa(model_ADI_aff,
                 data = bds_1,
                 missing = "fiml",
                 estimator = "MLR",
                 se = "robust.huber.white",
                 test = "yuan.bentler")
summary(fit_ADI_aff_1, standardized = TRUE, fit.measures = TRUE)
modindices(fit_ADI_aff_1, sort.=TRUE, minimum.value=3)

fit_ADI_aff_2 <- cfa(model_ADI_aff,
                     data = bds_2,
                     missing = "fiml",
                     estimator = "MLR",
                     se = "robust.huber.white",
                     test = "yuan.bentler")
summary(fit_ADI_aff_2, standardized = TRUE, fit.measures = TRUE)
modindices(fit_ADI_aff_2, sort.=TRUE, minimum.value=3)
```

...

Answer (score 1):

One way to make it simpler would be putting all your bds_x `data.frames` into a `list` and then running your model in all of them with `lapply()`

```
model_ADI_aff <- "aff =~ bds89 + bds39 + bds50 + bds29 + bds84 + bds49 + bds70 + bds88 + bds11 + bds28"

fun = function(bds){
 fit = cfa(model_ADI_aff,
           data = bds,
           missing = "fiml",
           estimator = "MLR",
           se = "robust.huber.white",
           test = "yuan.bentler")
 summ = summary(fit)
 mo = modindices(fit_ADI_aff_2, sort.=TRUE, minimum.value=3)

 list(fit = fit,summary = summ, modindices = mo)
}

df_list = "list containing all bds"
results = lapply(df_list,fun)
```

`results` will be a list of lists, each containing the fit, summary and modindices for each `data.frame`

Comment: Thank you for this reply, it's already helping me understand a bit more. However, as an output I'm not getting a list of lists, but simply one list. I suspect this has something to do with the argument 'data = bds_2' as this specifies the use of bds_2 as the df.
I tried changing this to df_list and deleting the argument all together, neither worked.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. It should be `bds`, as that's the function parameter. I edited the answer, it should work now.

Comment: Thank you so much, I made a couple of adjustments and it works now!

Answer (score 1):

@Fino

I made a few adjustments, and it seems to have done the trick, thank you so much!

```
fun = function(bds){
  fit = cfa(model_ADI_aff,
            data = bds,
            missing = "fiml",
            estimator = "MLR",
            se = "robust.huber.white",
            test = "yuan.bentler")
  summ = summary(fit, standardized = TRUE, fit.measures = TRUE)
  mo = modindices(fit, sort.=TRUE, minimum.value=3)

  list(fit = fit,summary = summ, modindices = mo)
}

df_list <- list (bds_1, bds_2, bds_3, bds_4, bds_5, bds_6, bds_7, bds_8)
results = lapply(df_list,fun)
```